# 2sxc - DNN Blog app

Tags: blogs, 2sxc

After updating 2sxc to the new 8.08 version my DNN blog app no longer displays the content within posts.

When you open the post you are met with, "No demo item exists for the selected template" Any ideas how to get this displaying the correct content again?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has to do with the update. apparently your app has a content-type assigned, but no demo-item. best go to the template/view configuration and either remove the content-type, or add a demo item (which won't show anyhow, once you have data)

Comment: Can you expand on this with some additional (step-by-step) details on how to correct this?  I haven't upgraded, but just installed the latest 2sxc app manager and the blog app.  This is my 1st use/test of 2sxc. So far I am REALLY impressed with them, but I am finding myself fumbling a bit with how it works.  I have the blog installed, it seems to be working perfectly except when I click a blog post (to bring up the post details) I'm getting the same "No demo item exists for the selected template." message.  THANKS.

Comment: @TedKrapf please create a new SO post for this, as it isn't directly related to the question above.

Comment: thanks - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403086/2sxc-blog-app-post-detail-page-no-demo-item-exists-for-the-selected-template