# 2SXC Blog App - Post Detail Page - No demo item exists for the selected template

Tags: blogs, 2sxc

When clicking a blog post to bring up the post's details page, the detail does not load.  Instead there is an error that reads "No demo item exists for the selected template."

Not sure what I'm missing.

Platform:
DNN v9.2.2, 
2sxc App v9.32.1, 
2sxc App Blog v03.00.02

This is my first install of 2sxc, love it thus far, thanks!
I added the blog app.  The 3 (or four) example blog posts were there and things seemed to be working correctly.  I edited the author to be one of our authors.  I deleted all the blog posts except the latest one.  The latest one I edited to a new actual post for the site.

When I click on the blog post to bring up it's full details, I get the "No demo item exists for the selected template." error message.  I also tried a new blog post, and the new post suffers from the same issue.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the site in question is: http://dnn.15dots.com/Blog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you "cleaned up" a bit, my guess is you probably deleted the demo-entry which is configured as a default for a view. This isn't a necessary entry, but usually helpful during development.

I suggest you go to app-administration (ellipsis button till you see a 1-gear-icon, click on that gear). Then go to views. Edit the view "Post Details" and either set the Content-Demo-Item to the one you still have, and you should be good to go :)

Comment: THANK YOU @iJungleBoy -- that did the trick.  I really appreciate you taking the time to help steer me in the right direction.  Keep up the excellent work!

Comment: you're welcome - and please spread the love - help others as well ;)

Comment: will definitely do! :)